# pl sql trigger how to compare column value in trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to create a ORACLE plsql trigger in my booking table which will prevent user to update value  where booking start date like <= sysdate.

in my booking table booking start date column name is date_from. I have tried following command but seems like I am using wrong code.

```
    create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_BOOKING
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF BOOKING.DATE_FROM <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
       THEN  
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'YOU CAN NOT UPDATE BOOKING STATUS WHERE ......');
    END IF;
END;
```

what would be the best way to implement this trigger.

Comment: Why not use a check constraint, rather than a trigger?

Comment: @DarenBeattie, you can't refer to a non-deterministic function (e.g. SYSDATE) in an ordinary check constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the existing value of the date then use `:old`. If you are updating the date column also and you want check it for the new value of update date then use `:new`. Example for `:old` is as follows..

```
create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_BOOKING
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :OLD.DATE_FROM <= TO_DATE(SYSDATE)
       THEN  
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'YOU CAN NOT UPDATE BOOKING STATUS WHERE ......');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use to_date() function for sysdate, its already date type, check the following code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER UPDATE_BOOKING
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- used trunc function below for more accuracy
    IF trunc(:OLD.DATE_FROM) <= trunc(SYSDATE)
       THEN  
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001,'YOU CAN NOT UPDATE BOOKING STATUS WHERE ......');
    END IF;
END;
```